# Download Qt SDK 1.1.2 for Symbian

Tags: qt, sdk, symbian, nokia, s60

I need to make some changes in application for Symbian s60 (Nokia X6). Unfortunatelly I can't find any working link where I can download Qt SDK 1.1.2 for Symbian.

Where can I find a working download link for Qt SDK 1.1.2 for Symbian?

Answer (score 3):

The link in the previous answer does not have the SDK 1.1.2 anymore, so in case someone still needs this, I uploaded it:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/7cwp6uchc2ouu1d/Qt_SDK_Win_offline_v1_1_2_en.exe

Answer (score 2):

Here's one link which appears to have then still: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Qt#Qt_SDK